# Use ConfigureAwait(false) in a Windows Service?

Tags: c#, windows-services, task-parallel-library, async-await, synchronizationcontext

As far as I know, there isn't a synchronization context in a Windows Service application.

- Does `await fooTask.ConfigureAwait(false)` give me any benefits in Windows Services?
- Are there any pitfalls to this?

Comment: There is no pitfalls, for as long as there is no code which would install a synchronization context. There is no benefits either, for as long as this code runs on a thread *without* synchronization context. It still makes sense for a shared class library.

Comment: @Noseratio Why don't you post that as an answer?

Comment: @svick, I now posted it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does await `fooTask.ConfigureAwait(false)` give me any benefits in
> Windows Services? Are there any pitfalls to this?

There is no pitfalls, for as long as there is no code which would install a synchronization context. There is no benefits either, for as long as this code runs on a thread without synchronization context.

Nevertheless, this code still would make sense for a shared class library, aimed to be used in different execution environments.

If you did have a synchronization context, there [might be some pitfalls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22672984/configureawait-pushes-the-continuation-to-a-pool-thread).

**Updated:** it's now 2021 and here's what I think about [using `ConfigureAwait` these days](https://dev.to/noseratio/why-i-no-longer-use-configureawait-false-3pne).