# A task that will never end until cancellation is requested

Tags: .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I need a task that never ends until cancellation is requested. At the moment [the simplest way to do that is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13695674/2528649):

```
var cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();

var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(10000, cancellation.Token);
    }
}, cancellation.Token).Unwrap();
```

What I don't like is a call to `Task.Delay` method because it requires limited time interval for waiting.

Is there more elegant solution?

Comment: Does the task need to count as being started? Also, even if you ignore the possibility of an infinite timeout, you can still give `TimeSpan.MaxValue` which simply won't finish...

Comment: Yes, the task is started. Regarding `TimeSpan.MaxValue` Im not sure if it will work, I haven't found any information in docs.

Comment: That task *is* started - but do you *need* it to be started?

Comment: In 99% cases yes, I need the task to be started. Why do you ask, is it significant?

Comment: I was thinking of `TaskCompletionSource`, as Lee suggested - but a `TaskCompletionSource`-based task which hasn't been finished is in state `WaitingForActivation`, which may not be appropriate for you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As an alternative to `TaskCompletionSource` with `token.Register`, here are some one-liners:

```
var task = new Task(() => {}, token); // don't do task.Run()!
```

Or, simply this:

```
var task = Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, token);
```

There's even a nice optimization for `Timeout.Infinite` in the [current `Task.Delay` implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs#5fb80297e082b8d6).

Comment: Last case I think is the simplest so the most elegant, looks great. I forgot about this "magic" constant `Timeout.Infinite`, luckily this method accepts it.

Answer (score 9):

You should be able to subscribe to the cancellation of the token and complete the task then:

```
public static Task UntilCancelled(CancellationToken tok)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    IDisposable subscription = null;
    subscription = tok.Register(() =>
    {
        tcs.SetResult(null);
        subscription.Dispose();
    });

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: This is nice. And you can really slim it down with this: `using var subscription = tok.Register(() => tcs.SetResult(null)); await tcs.Task;`