# Can I cancel StreamReader.ReadLineAsync with a CancellationToken?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, cancellation-token

When I cancel my async method with the following content by calling the `Cancel()` method of my `CancellationTokenSource`, it will stop eventually. However since the line `Console.WriteLine(await reader.ReadLineAsync());` takes quite a bit to complete, I tried to pass my `CancellationToken` to `ReadLineAsync()` as well (expecting it to return an empty string) in order to make the method more responsive to my `Cancel()` call. However I could not pass a `CancellationToken` to `ReadLineAsync()`.

Can I cancel a call to `Console.WriteLine()` or `Streamreader.ReadLineAsync()` and if so, how do I do it?

Why is `ReadLineAsync()` not accepting a `CancellationToken`? I thought it was good practice to give async methods an optional `CancellationToken` parameter even if the method still completes after being canceled.

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    if (ct.IsCancellationRequested){
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(await reader.ReadLineAsync());
    }
}
```

**Update**:
Like stated in the comments below, the `Console.WriteLine()` call alone was already taking up several seconds due to a poorly formatted input string of 40.000 characters per line. Breaking this down solves my response-time issues, but I am still interested in any suggestions or workarounds on how to cancel this long-running statement if for some reason writing 40.000 characters into one line was intended (for example when dumping the whole string into a file).

Comment: You are trying to solve the wrong problem.  You wrote an exceedingly user-hostile program, it is crazily scrolling text across the screen at a rate far higher than the user can ever read.  Now you are looking for the "stop this nonsense" solution.  Of course you are, your user would too.  But that's not the real solution, the proper one is never get it started in the first place.  Write it to a file, display it with Notepad.  Anything is better.

Comment: `You are trying to solve the wrong problem.` Thank you for being this clear - you are absolutely right.

Comment: The real question is about how to cancel ReadLineAsync which is not instant, think TcpSocket. The ConsoleWriteLine is just noise.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't cancel the operation unless it's cancellable. You can use the `WithCancellation` extension method to have your code flow behave as if it was cancelled, but the underlying would still run:

```
public static Task<T> WithCancellation<T>(this Task<T> task, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return task.IsCompleted // fast-path optimization
        ? task
        : task.ContinueWith(
            completedTask => completedTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult(),
            cancellationToken,
            TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
            TaskScheduler.Default);
}
```

Usage:

```
await task.WithCancellation(cancellationToken);
```

You can't cancel `Console.WriteLine` and you don't need to. It's instantaneous if you have a reasonable sized `string`.

About the guideline: If your implementation doesn't actually support cancellation you shouldn't be accepting a token since it sends a mixed message.

If you do have a huge string to write to the console you shouldn't use `Console.WriteLine`. You can write the string in a character at a time and have that method be cancellable:

```
public void DumpHugeString(string line, CancellationToken token)
{
    foreach (var character in line)
    {
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        Console.Write(character);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

An even better solution would be to write in batches instead of single characters. Here's an implementation using `MoreLinq`'s `Batch`:

```
public void DumpHugeString(string line, CancellationToken token)
{
    foreach (var characterBatch in line.Batch(100))
    {
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        Console.Write(characterBatch.ToArray());
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

So, in conclusion:

```
var reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    DumpHugeString(await reader.ReadLineAsync().WithCancellation(token), token);
}
```

Comment: @HW you can't cancel `Console.WriteLine` unless it supports cancellation, but you can use `Console.Write` little by little. See my update.

Comment: Are you sure `Task.ContinueWith` will cancel the entire taks as well? From my point of view `Task.ContinueWith` is not suitable here. You need something like `Task.WhenAny(task, infiniteCancellableTaks)` where `var infiniteCancellableTaks = Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, token)`, like in this example http://stackoverflow.com/a/23473779/2528649

Comment: @neleus Yes. It won't cancel the original task (because you can't) but it will cancel the continuation. Feel free to try it out.

Comment: You are right, it works. For me It looks unobvious but this is off topic.

Comment: @neleus That's just because we're used to the whole `Task.Delay` hack. Using a continuation that either completes when the task completes or is cancelled when the token is canceled is actually much more elegant and reasonable.

Comment: Agree that `Task.ContinueWith` is better, didn't know about such solution.

Answer (score 14):

.NET 6 brings [Task.WaitAsync(CancellationToken)](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/48842). So one can write:

```
using StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{       
    Console.WriteLine(await reader.ReadLineAsync().WaitAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false));
}
```

In .NET 7 (not yet released), it should be possible to write simply:

```
using StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{       
    Console.WriteLine(await reader.ReadLineAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

based on https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/20824 and  https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/61898.

Comment: True, but In that case you don't need construct with the check for `EndOfStream`. `ReadLineAsync` will just return `null` when the end-of-stream is reached. (Also: put the reader in a `using` declaration)

Comment: It's a snippet showing something, it was not written to copy&paste to your code for production. True, it should be better and I added the usings. Feel free to propose any improvement directly to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Might be, but you know how many people actually do copy paste stack overflow code...

Answer (score 3):

I generalized this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211972/getresponseasync-does-not-accept-cancellationtoken) to this:

```
public static async Task<T> WithCancellation<T>(this Task<T> task, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Action action, bool useSynchronizationContext = true)
{
    using (cancellationToken.Register(action, useSynchronizationContext))
    {
        try
        {
            return await task;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                // the Exception will be available as Exception.InnerException
                throw new OperationCanceledException(ex.Message, ex, cancellationToken);
            }

            // cancellation hasn't been requested, rethrow the original Exception
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use your cancellation token on any cancelable async method. For example WebRequest.GetResponseAsync:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

using (var response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
{
    . . .
}
```

will become:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync().WithCancellation(CancellationToken.None, request.Abort, true))
{
    . . .
}
```

See example http://pastebin.com/KauKE0rW

Comment: There is a race in the example. If you check `IsCancellationRequested` in the catch handler, you do not know if the cancellation or exception has happened first.

You should check for the exception type to see if it really is a cancellation exception.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use an infinite delay, the code is quite clean.
If `waiting` is complete `WhenAny` returns and the `cancellationToken` will throw. Else, the result of `task` will be returned.

```
public static async Task<T> WithCancellation<T>(this Task<T> task, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
        using (var delayCTS = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken))
        {
            var waiting = Task.Delay(-1, delayCTS.Token);
            var doing = task;
            await Task.WhenAny(waiting, doing);
            delayCTS.Cancel();
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            return await doing;
        }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can't cancel `Streamreader.ReadLineAsync()`. IMHO this is because reading a single line should be very quick. But you can easily prevent the `Console.WriteLine()` from happening by using a separate task variable.

The check for `ct.IsCancellationRequested` is also redundand as `ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` will only throw if cancellation is requested.

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    string line = await reader.ReadLineAsync());

    ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();    
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint that i do not need to check for `IsCancellationRequested`! Sadly Checking again for the cancellation between the two tasks hardly decreased my response time.

Comment: Reading a single line could be very slow, if for example you are reading a stdout stream, or a network stream, i.e. any stream whose contents are not fully materialized in one shot.

Comment: Like said above, ReadLineAsync() can take long time, for example, in case of TCP connection, where a server thread is waiting for the client to send a line of text.