# SSH.NET real-time command output monitoring

Tags: wpf, ssh, async-await, monitoring, ssh.net

There is a long running script `script.sh` on a remote Linux machine. I need to start it and monitor it's activity in real time. The script during it's activity may output to `stdout` and `stderr`. I am searching for a way to capture both of the streams.

I use Renci SSH.NET to upload `script.sh` and start it, so it would be great to see a solution bounded to this library. In my mind the perfect solution is the new method:

```cs
var realTimeScreen= ...;

var commandExecutionStatus = sshClient.RunCommandAsync(
    command: './script.sh',
    stdoutEventHandler: stdoutString => realTimeScreen.UpdateStdout(stdString)
    stderrEventHandler: stderrString => realTimeScreen.UpdateStderr(stderrString));
...
commandExecutionStatus.ContinueWith(monitoringTask =>
{
    if (monitoringTask.Completed)
    {
        realTimeScreen.Finish();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So, here is the solution I came up with. Of course, it can be improved, so it is open to critique.
I used

```cs
await Dispatcher.Yield(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);
```

instead of `Task.Yield()` because `Task.Yield()` will make continuation a higher priority than GUI events, but, as a bad consequence, it demands your application to use `WindowsBase.dll`.

```cs
public static class SshCommandExtensions
{
    public static async Task ExecuteAsync(
        this SshCommand sshCommand,
        IProgress<ScriptOutputLine> progress,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var asyncResult = sshCommand.BeginExecute();
        var stdoutStreamReader = new StreamReader(sshCommand.OutputStream);
        var stderrStreamReader = new StreamReader(sshCommand.ExtendedOutputStream);

        while (!asyncResult.IsCompleted)
        {
            await CheckOutputAndReportProgress(
                sshCommand,
                stdoutStreamReader,
                stderrStreamReader,
                progress,
                cancellationToken);

            await Dispatcher.Yield(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);
        }

        sshCommand.EndExecute(asyncResult);

        await CheckOutputAndReportProgress(
            sshCommand,
            stdoutStreamReader,
            stderrStreamReader,
            progress,
            cancellationToken);
    }

    private static async Task CheckOutputAndReportProgress(
        SshCommand sshCommand,
        TextReader stdoutStreamReader,
        TextReader stderrStreamReader,
        IProgress<ScriptOutputLine> progress,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            sshCommand.CancelAsync();
        }
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        await CheckStdoutAndReportProgressAsync(stdoutStreamReader, progress);
        await CheckStderrAndReportProgressAsync(stderrStreamReader, progress);
    }

    private static async Task CheckStdoutAndReportProgressAsync(
        TextReader stdoutStreamReader,
        IProgress<ScriptOutputLine> stdoutProgress)
    {
        var stdoutLine = await stdoutStreamReader.ReadToEndAsync();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stdoutLine))
        {
            stdoutProgress.Report(new ScriptOutputLine(
                line: stdoutLine,
                isErrorLine: false));
        }
    }

    private static async Task CheckStderrAndReportProgressAsync(
        TextReader stderrStreamReader,
        IProgress<ScriptOutputLine> stderrProgress)
    {
        var stderrLine = await stderrStreamReader.ReadToEndAsync();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stderrLine))
        {
            stderrProgress.Report(new ScriptOutputLine(
                line: stderrLine,
                isErrorLine: true));
        }
    }
}

public class ScriptOutputLine
{
    public ScriptOutputLine(string line, bool isErrorLine)
    {
        Line = line;
        IsErrorLine = isErrorLine;
    }

    public string Line { get; private set; }

    public bool IsErrorLine { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: could you please give a code snippet to explain how to use these functions? I am new to .Net

Comment: await client.CreateCommand("sleep 1; echo 1; sleep 1; echo 2; ps -ax | grep java").ExecuteAsync(progress, new CancellationToken()); only yields one line with "1" for me. This seems to not be correct.

Comment: If you move the `sshCommand.EndExecute(asyncResult);` line to the end of the method, it works better

Comment: The `sshCommand.EndExecute(asyncResult);` should be at the end, after `CheckOutputAndReportProgress`.

Answer (score 20):

Use `SshClient.CreateCommand` method. It returns `SshCommand` instance.

The `SshCommand` class has `OutputStream` (and `Result`) for stdout and `ExtendedOutputStream` for stderr.

See `SshCommandTest.cs`:

```cs
public void Test_Execute_ExtendedOutputStream()
{
    var host = Resources.HOST;
    var username = Resources.USERNAME;
    var password = Resources.PASSWORD;

    using (var client = new SshClient(host, username, password))
    {
        #region Example SshCommand CreateCommand Execute ExtendedOutputStream

        client.Connect();
        var cmd = client.CreateCommand("echo 12345; echo 654321 >&2");
        var result = cmd.Execute();

        Console.Write(result);

        var reader = new StreamReader(cmd.ExtendedOutputStream);
        Console.WriteLine("DEBUG:");
        Console.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());

        client.Disconnect();

        #endregion

        Assert.Inconclusive();
    }
}
```

---

See also a full code for similar WinForms question [Execute long time command in SSH.NET and display the results continuously in TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47386713/850848).

Comment: Thank you for insights with `cmd.Execute()` and `OutputStreams`. After I finish polishing the code I will post here a wrapper that is perfect for my situation.
Once again, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

The following code waits for output and error output independently and has good performance.

```c
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Renci.SshNet;

namespace DockerTester
{
    public static class SshCommandExtensions
    {
        public static async Task ExecuteAsync(
            this SshCommand sshCommand,
            IProgress<ScriptOutputLine> progress,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var asyncResult = sshCommand.BeginExecute();
            var stdoutReader = new StreamReader(sshCommand.OutputStream);
            var stderrReader = new StreamReader(sshCommand.ExtendedOutputStream);

            var stderrTask = CheckOutputAndReportProgressAsync(sshCommand, asyncResult, stderrReader, progress, true, cancellationToken);
            var stdoutTask = CheckOutputAndReportProgressAsync(sshCommand, asyncResult, stdoutReader, progress, false, cancellationToken);

            await Task.WhenAll(stderrTask, stdoutTask);

            sshCommand.EndExecute(asyncResult);
        }

        private static async Task CheckOutputAndReportProgressAsync(
            SshCommand sshCommand,
            IAsyncResult asyncResult,
            StreamReader streamReader,
            IProgress<ScriptOutputLine> progress,
            bool isError,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            while (!asyncResult.IsCompleted || !streamReader.EndOfStream)
            {
                if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    sshCommand.CancelAsync();
                }

                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                var stderrLine = await streamReader.ReadLineAsync();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stderrLine))
                {
                    progress.Report(new ScriptOutputLine(
                        line: stderrLine,
                        isErrorLine: isError));
                }

                // wait 10 ms
                await Task.Delay(10, cancellationToken);
            }
        }
    }

    public class ScriptOutputLine
    {
        public ScriptOutputLine(string line, bool isErrorLine)
        {
            Line = line;
            IsErrorLine = isErrorLine;
        }

        public string Line { get; private set; }

        public bool IsErrorLine { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

You can use it:

```cs
var outputs = new Progress<ScriptOutputLine>(ReportProgress);

using (var command =
    sshClient.RunCommand(
        "LONG_RUNNING_COMMAND"))
{
    await command.ExecuteAsync(outputs, CancellationToken.None);
    await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("Status code: " + command.ExitStatus);
}
```

And example implementation of the method for reporting progress:

```cs
private static void ReportProgress(ScriptOutputLine obj)
{
    var color = Console.ForegroundColor;
    if (obj.IsErrorLine)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine(obj.Line);
        Console.ForegroundColor = color;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Line);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Wojtpl2's answer. For commands like "tail -f" one of the streamer tasks will lock on ReadLine method:

```
var stderrLine = await streamReader.ReadLineAsync();
```

To overcome this, we need to pass token to streamReader with extension method:

```
        public static Task<T> WithCancellation<T>(this Task<T> task, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return task.IsCompleted // fast-path optimization
                ? task
                : task.ContinueWith(
                    completedTask => completedTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult(),
                    cancellationToken,
                    TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
                    TaskScheduler.Default);
        }
```

thx to [Can I cancel StreamReader.ReadLineAsync with a CancellationToken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28626575/can-i-cancel-streamreader-readlineasync-with-a-cancellationtoken)

and use it like this:

```
var stderrLine = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync().WithCancellation(cancellationToken);
```