# Executing command using SSH.NET produces no output

Tags: c#, winforms, ssh, ssh.net

I am trying to make a program that connects to an SSH server and then logs me in. I have successfully created tracert or ping commands, but SSH connection doesn't work for me at all. I am using SSH.NET. I get no output to my text box. I already followed some advice from StackOverflow ([Execute long time command in SSH.NET and display the results continuously in TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47386713/execute-long-time-command-in-ssh-net-and-display-the-results-continuously-in-tex)), but it did not work for me.

Here's the code:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string host = "someserverip";
    string username = textBox6.Text;
    string password = textBox8.Text;
    string ipaddress = textBox12.Text;

    using (var radius = new SshClient(host, port, username, password))
    {
        radius.Connect();
        var cmd = radius.CreateCommand("check-host" + ipaddress);
        var result = cmd.BeginExecute();

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(
              cmd.OutputStream, Encoding.UTF8, true, 1024, true))
        {
            while (!result.IsCompleted || !reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                if (line != null)
                {
                    textBox10.Invoke(
                        (Action)(() =>
                            textBox10.AppendText(line + Environment.NewLine)));
                }
            }
        }
        cmd.EndExecute(result);
    }
    textBox10.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something probably goes wrong with your command and as you are not reading the error output, you won't know.

- Try reading the `ExtendedOutputStream` to see any error output the command might produce.
- To ease debugging you can (temporarily) merge both streams into one using `2>&1` shell syntax.

---

Though in your code, you miss a space between command name and its arguments. It should rather be

```
"check-host " + ipaddress
```

Answer (score -1):

With SSH.NET you can implement a check on the ExitStatus of your executed command to give you a good idea of what is occurring... and of course, you can check your logs for any error messages contained in them. I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but hopefully it gets you or someone else in the right direction. Also, I have never heard of a check-host command, are you trying to execute a script named check-host, or maybe trying to execute the host command? Anyways, here goes:

```
using (var sshClient = new SshClient(host, user, password))
{
    sshClient.Connect();

    var cmd = sshClient.CreateCommand("cd /some/directory/where/scriptlives/; ./check-host.sh " + ipaddress); 
    var asyncExecute = cmd.BeginExecute();
    var result = cmd.Result;
    var status = cmd.ExitStatus; //Returns SSH Code

    if(status == 0)
    {
       //Do additional work here
    }
    else
    {
       //Handle the exception here
    }

}
```

Partial list of SSH Return Codes 0 to 255

0 - Operation was successful

1 - Generic error, usually because invalid command line options

2 - Connection failed

65 - Host not allowed to connect

66 - General error in SSH protocol

67 - Key exchange failed

68 - Reserved

69 - MAC error

70 - Compression error

71 - Service not available

72 - Protocol version not supported

73 - Host key not verifiable

74 - Connection failed

75 - Disconnected by application

76 - Too many connections

77 - Authentication cancelled by user

78 - No more authentication methods available

79 - Invalid user name

255 - SSH fails after being executed by another process, permissions
denied, etc.

Comment: Wny source for these codes? And what do supposed *"SSH exit codes"* have to do with executing a shell command?

Comment: Hi... From the OP's question, it wasn't exactly clear that he was able to execute a command. He said that the SSH connection doesn't work for him at all, but that could mean many things, so if he is using the ExitStatus() he can get the error code from the connection or connection attempt.