# how to implement cancellation with yield return readlineAsync()

Tags: c#

How do I implement cancellation when running a cmd-file correctly?
Currently I use this code:

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<string?> ExecuteCmdFile(string parameters, [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var startInfo =
        new ProcessStartInfo(_cmdFilePath, parameters) { RedirectStandardOutput = true, CreateNoWindow = true };
    using var p = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo };
    p.Start();
    while (!p.HasExited)
    {
        if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            p.Kill();
            yield return "Operation aborted";
        }
        else
        {
            yield return await p.StandardOutput.ReadLineAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Cancellation generally works but - depending on the task currently running - it may take a while, because the process first has to wait for `ReadLineAsync()` to return a value
before `cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested()` is checked again and can be acted upon.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28626769/2109769?

Comment: this looks promising. thanks @Quercus !